# How to set up a Linux "external" server that proxy/route external requests to a server accessible only on a VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy

I am going to set up a Linux server attached to my university network, but this server will be accessible only from our local network, or externally trough the VPN of our organisation.
I need however to make this server visible from the wider world, for example to provide NextCloud service to project partners that are not part of our organisation.

I am thinking to rent a cheap Linux VPS and use it to proxy (and, I guess, firewall) requests from the outer world and route them, trough a VPN connection, to the specific server I am setting up.

2 questions:

1. Is this a good idea? Dangerous? Would I likely break university  policies?
2. Which would be the general set up / software pieces to install ? (we use the latest Ubuntu LTS)

Comment: `Would I likely break university policies?` probably, but you need to discuss that with the university.